# Camera vector to Tangent

Tags: node-editor, shaders

Pretty new to Blender, coming from Unreal and I'm trying to convert a Camera Vector to a Tangent Vector.
Vector Transform Node (similar is also found in Unreal) doesn't seem to convert to Tangent.

Any ideas on this please?

Thanks